# Valiant comic issue where a necromancer ushers his zombies onto a bus and they start singing "The Wheels on the Bus"

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification, valiant-comics

I'm 90% certain that this was a Valiant comic, the original setting under Jim Shooter before Acclaim bought them up. I think I read it in the early 90s. The Dollar Tree had bags with 2-3 random issues. I mainly kept buying them to read *Archer & Armstrong*, but I remember also reading issues of *Shadowman*, *The H.A.R.D. Corps*, and *Harbingers*, and of course there were multiple crossovers. In one of the issues, I remember a necromancer had raised a bunch of zombies, and promptly started loading them on a bus, where they all started singing "[The Wheels on the Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wheels_on_the_Bus)". The scene was so ridiculous that it's stuck in my head now, almost 30 years later.

It might have been [Master Darque](https://valiant.fandom.com/wiki/Master_Darque_(Valiant_Comics)), mainly since he's one of the most prevalent necromancers in the universe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain the song was "The Wheels on the Bus"...? In [Archer & Armstrong Vol 1 #21](https://valiant.fandom.com/wiki/Archer_%26_Armstrong_Vol_1_21), there's a scene almost identical to what you've described, except that the song being sung is "[The Hearse Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hearse_Song)". The necromancer in question was indeed Master Darque.

[image]

Comment: I was indeed wrong. Thank you. That sets my mind much more at ease to know where to find it.